# Copy Excel text box content into Word document

Tags: excel, vba, text, ms-word, box

I'm wondering if there is a similar script like

```
.Sheets("VEF").ChartObjects(1).Copy
.paste
```

For a text box (text box as found under insert->text->text box)

Comment: Is there a question? Please see [ask]. What exactly have you tried and where did you get stuck or errors?

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't work with Word, since it's a simple copy & paste within Excel.

Comment: This is only a small part of the code (Word document is opened, some other stuff is added...). This part copies the chart from Excel into my word document. No problem here. I'm searching for a way to copy a text box from Excel (text box is type insert-> text -> text box) into Word. with the .copy and .paste method. Something similar as the ChartObject methode.